# Wrong parameter count for str_replace() error

Tags: php, string, str-replace

```
<?php
$kw = $_POST["kw"];
$kw= str_replace("*","%",$kw,$count);
if($count > 1) 
{
echo "not supported";
exit;
}
...
?>
```

I'm getting this warning "Wrong parameter count for str_replace() error".

where am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: navigating to `php.net/{functionname}` will give you the respective manual page, which will tell you in which PHP version the fourth parameter was added. E.g. http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using? I suspect <5.0.0

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

> 5.0.0  The count parameter was added.

Comment: Indeed. PHP 5 has been out for nearly seven years. PHP 4 was supported concurrently for those slow to upgrade, but it's been officially unsupported for three years now. Time to upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$kw= str_replace("*","%",$kw,&$count);
```

Comment: No. `$count` is a reference in the function definition (which is the proper way to do it), so this is redundant at best. And, doing it this way is not supported/recommended. 'As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated.' [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)